# How to optimize if else statement to Map using java code

Tags: java, sql, collections

I am new to java I want to optimize my code using Map in java. When I
write my Code I use lot of if else statement so I want reduce my code
using  map of collection framework When I implement Map i am not get
accurate result. My Function totally not working. Here Is my code.

```
private List<Item> getBussinessSearchItem(IteamSearch itemSearch, byte searchType,int size, int offSet){
        StringBuilder  queryBuilder - new StringBuilder();
        
        if(itemSearch.getOrigin()!=null && (checkOriginDomain(itemSearch.getOrigin))) {
            if(itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                if(itemSearch.getSortOrder() == 1) {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY Name ASc");
                }else {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY Name ASc");
                }
            }else if(itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("upc1")) {
                if(itemSearch.getSortOrder() == 1) {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY upc1 ASc");
                }else {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY upc1 ASc");
                }
            }
            else if(itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("minQuantiy")) {
                if(itemSearch.getSortOrder() == 1) {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY minQuantiy ASc");
                }else {
                    queryBuilder.append("ORDDER BY minQuantiy ASc");
                }
            }
        }
```

when I use this above statement it works fine and give me result
properly sorting with ASCENDING AND DESCINDING order. But I do not
want to implement above statement I want to implement map and that map
works same as the above statement.
Here is my code but this below code not working

```
private Map<String , String> getBussinessSearchItem(ItemSearch itemSearch){
        Map<Srring,String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
        itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("name");
        itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("upc1");
        itemSearch.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase("minQuantiy");
    }
```

I do not know how to implement map instead of if else statement. I
want  solve  this issue using map  or enum.

My ItemSerach table contain name,upc1,minquantity

Comment: Right now your code always orders by ascending. Typo?

Comment: besides, it now spells ordder

Comment: Your code does nothing with the map, so of course it doesn't work. Your map is, in fact, empty. I'd start with filling it with what you want it to hold, and then worry about how to get what you want from it. Or rather, I'd start learning JPA or something like that and stop building my queries with a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If you move sort options to a separate class `ItemSearchOrder` class which implements `equals` and `hashCode` properly, you could use it directly as key in your map:

```
class ItemSearchOrder {
  private final String sort;
  private final int order;
  public ItemSearchOrder(final String sort, final int order) {
    this.sort = Objects.requireNonNull(sort);
    this.order = order;
  }

  public static ItemSearchOrder asc(final String sort) {
    return new ItemSearchOrder(sort, 1);
  }

  public static ItemSearchOrder desc(final String sort) {
    return new ItemSearchOrder(sort, 0);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;

    return this.order == other.order
      && this.sort.equalsIgnoreCase(other.sort);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(sort, order);
  }
}
```

Then build your map:

```
final Map<ItemSearchOrder, String> sortQueries = Map.ofEntries(
  Map.entry(ItemSearchOrder.asc("name")), "ORDER BY name ASC"),
  Map.entry(ItemSearchOrder.desc("name")), "ORDER BY name DESC"),
  Map.entry(ItemSearchOrder.asc("upc1")), "ORDER BY upc1 ASC"),
  ...
);
```

And then use it to look up the correct ORDER BY clause:

```
public List<Item> getBussinessSearchItem(
    final IteamSearch itemSearch, ...) {
  final String sort = sortQueries.get(itemSearch.getOrder());
  if (sort == null) {
    // unknown sort
  }

  // ...
}
```